# Thymeleaf: How to use #numbers.sequence() with a variable limit?

Tags: html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm calling an int value from a database to determine the number of stars that should be displayed in my html using thymeleaf and Spring Boot, but using ${#numbers.sequence(1,obj.stars)} doesn't seem to work.

this is my html-thymeleaf code:

```
    <tr th:each="obj : ${allObjs}" class="pointer" th:onclick="'javascript:openobj(\'' + ${obj.id} + '\');'">
    <td class="text-center" th:text="${obj.id}"></td>
    <td class="text-center" th:text="${obj.code}"></td>
    <td class="text-center" th:text="${obj.name}"></td>
    <td class="text-center" th:text="${obj.contract}"></td>
    <td class="text-center" th:text="${obj.difficulty}"></td>
    <td class="text-center" th:text="${obj.priority}"></td>
    <td class="text-center">
        <!--this is the line I can't get to work :(-->
        <span class="fa fa-star-o" th:each="star:${#numbers.sequence(1,obj.stars)}"></span> 
    </td>
    <td class="text-center" th:text="${obj.state}"></td>
    <td class="text-center" th:text="${obj.percent}"></td>
    <td class="text-center" th:text="${obj.term}"></td>
    <td class="text-center" th:text="${obj.version}"></td>
    <td class="text-center" th:text="${obj.price}"></td>
</tr>
```

and my controller

```
 @GetMapping("/Obj")
 public ModelAndView index() {
      ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("/Obj/index");
      view.addObject("title", "Obj");
      List<Obj> allObjs = ObjService.findAll();
      view.addObject("allObjs", allObjs);
      return view;
 }
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting?  That thymeleaf code is correct (just tested it).  Have you verified the view-source, and made sure it isn't something with your css?

Comment: the Error is this:
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "#numbers.sequence(1,obj.stars)" (/Obj/index)

Comment: does obj.stars resolve to an integer?

Comment: jum, maybe that's the problem. I don't know how to make #numbers.sequence see obj.stars as an integer

Comment: stars is defined as private int stars; in the entity

Comment: is there a way to loop through chars from 'a' to 'z' in a similar way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, I know it's weird to answer your own question but, thanks to Michael Petch who tested it, I found that the problem was in the sequence. It was starting from 1 when I had values of 0 in obj.stars so the sequence couldn't be created with a step of 1.

Changing it to

```
<span class="fa fa-star-o" th:each="star:${#numbers.sequence(0,obj.stars)}"></span>
```

Solved the problem.