# How to use variables from a Constants class in thymeleaf numbers.sequence() method?

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I have two static variables defined in a `Constants` class like this

```java
public static String MIN_VALUE = 1;
public static String MAX_VALUE = 10;
```

I want to create a html select tag with options with all numbers starting from `MIN_VALUE` to `MAX_VALUE`. I can easily do this if I use hardcoded numbers in thymeleaf:

```java
<select>
  <option th:each="number: ${#numbers.sequence(1, 10)}" th:value="${number}" th:text="${number}"/>
</select>
```

But if I try something like this:

```java
<option th:each="number: ${#numbers.sequence(${Constants.MIN_VALUES}, ${Constants.MAX_VALUES})}" th:value="${number}" th:text="${number}"/>
```

I get this error:

```
EL1043E: Unexpected token. Expected 'rparen())' but was 'lcurly({)'
```

How can I use variable from my `Constant` class in thymeleaf's `numbers.sequence` method?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41149380/thymeleaf-how-to-use-numbers-sequence-with-a-variable-limit) question with almost similar title, but I am not passing my variable limits via `model` attribute here. I can access my variables from `Constants` class using `Constants.VAR_NAME` from thymeleaf tags.

Comment: You'd need `T(com.example.Constants).MIN_VALUE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Don't nest `${...}` expressions.
2. Use `T(com.example.Constants).MIN_VALUE` as stated in the comments. (Where `com.example.Constants` is the complete package and class name.)

Example:

```
<select>
  <option
    th:each="number: ${#numbers.sequence(T(com.example.Constants).MIN_VALUE, T(com.example.Constants).MAX_VALUE)}"
    th:value="${number}"
    th:text="${number}" />
</select>
```